# Error while activating virtual environment in Windows 10 PowerShell

Tags: powershell, virtualenv

I get an error while activating virtual environment in Windows 10 PowerShell :

```bsh
PS C:\Users\sunil\Desktop\my_projects> .\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1
.\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1 : The term '.\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1' is
not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
that the path is correct and try again.
```

Even trying this way:

```bsh
PS C:\Users\sunil\Desktop\my_projects\venv> .\Scripts\activate
Program 'activate' failed to run: No application is associated with the
specified file for this operationAt line:1 char:1
    + .\Scripts\activate
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
```

Comment: You're aboutely certain `C:\Users\sunil\Desktop\my_projects\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1` exists? Does `Get-Item .\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1` return the file?

Comment: I didn't get your question,sorry . Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Windows, then navigate to `<venv>\Scripts`, where `<venv>` is the name of your virtual environment. Then, execute the following command:

```
set-Executionpolicy -Executionpolicy Remotesigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Type `activate` and press return. You will now be able to use your virtual environment.